# VSS - To get files from VSS after a specific date

Tags: vbscript, visual-sourcesafe, batch-file

Need to get files from VSS after a specific file.

Eg: 
`$/test/hello1` --> I need to get all the files checked in under `$/test/` after a date 05/20/2012 to my local desktop.

Please help me in vbscript or batch script.

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about this very thing back in 2009.. [*SourceSafe history report - from the command line*](http://techfilth.blogspot.co.nz/2009/08/sometimes-it-is-really-useful-to-be.html).
Here is an excerpt (there is still some more explanation of the parameters on the blog post):

> Sometimes it is really useful to be able to do a history report on your SourceSafe archive. For instance, what check-ins did the developer called X make between 1 June 2009 and 30 June 2009?
>
> Surprisingly it can be tough to search out the exact info you need to make this work effectively. Having this sort of reporting is also really helpful when putting together release notes, especially if developers use the 'comment' feature when checking items in, and mention specific bug cases (you are using a bug tracking product, aren't you?).
>
> Here is how you do it. Open up a command prompt. Then you need to set an environmental variable called SSDIR, this is so the following commands know what repository we will be working with. To do this type the path to the folder containing the srcsafe.ini file of the repository:
>
> C:>set SSDIR=c:\Program Files\Sourcesafe\
>
> Note the trailing slash, and note that the filename itself is not included. Then you need to navigate to the folder where sourcesafe is installed:
>
> C:>cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe
>
> Then we use ss.exe to generate the history report. This particular command gives me all the files that were checked in between 0900 on the 1st July and 0900 on the 30th July.
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe>ss history "$/Projects/My Project" -Oc:\history.txt -R -vd30/07/09;09:00a~01/07/09;09:00a

Comment: how about obtain the files with a specific comment?